# RSS Reader that can fetch and show the older items of a feed

Tags: software-recommendation, rss, google-reader

Google Reader shows all the older entries of a feed but this service is going to close soon.

So is there a feed reader for Ubuntu or any online service which can fetch and show the older entries of a feed too - like say 6 months old or more. In case of Google Reader one can scroll down to have the older entries.

I am preparing for the competitive exams and I do not read newspapers daily and I find this to be a convenient way to be updated about current affairs at once.

Comment: Ok, so here's the deal: If you're going to answer with a **webapp**, you should include instructions for integration with unity webapps or Chrome webapps.

Comment: ? please elaborate i did not get you

Comment: @gunjanparashar Don't worry about it; that comment is mostly for people providing answers as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I use the webapp: http://www.feedly.com/

You can import your google reader accuont. You can install chrome and firefox extensions, but android app is not the best.

Enjoy!

Comment: it worked just need to uncheck the unread only option thank you

Comment: @gunjan parashar, It doesn't work for groups (still 1 month displayed)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout SwarmIQ. Similar functionality.

Features: The ability to skim large #s of headlines, organize lots of feeds, label them, tag articles for later reading, fastm unobtrusive "no magazine layout".
Sign up at http://www.swarmiq.com/register/GOOGLEREADERISDEAD , click on the Google reader icon to get all your feeds, and get up and running straight away.

Disclosure: I'm on the team that built this site :-) Also, we don't have "Google Alerts" type functionality yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend RssOwl. It's a Java app but fairly decent and works well with Ubuntu as far as I can tell. And as all the newsfeeds are saved on your own computer, you alone decide when and if something should be deleted from them.

http://www.rssowl.org/

Comment: i need a rss reader to read the old news as in case of the google reader one can scroll down to read the old feed , please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can try [elonreader](http://eldonreader.com). It's really good. They have a web app and I think an ubuntu app as well. Im not sure.

Comment: not working as i need , not getting the older feeds

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird works the best with both mail and RSS feeds. It also has a search function and can store past feed history to infinity.

Comment: I think the OP wants it to be able to fetch old posts, like install it now and get posts from 2011. I'm not even sure this is possible though.

Comment: yes with google reader just scroll down you will get the older entries too

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out TinyTinyRSS? You can even install it on your own webspace.

-> http://tt-rss.org/

Comment: after a lot of efforts i installed it but not getting the older feed like as in google reader

Answer (score 0):

The Opera web browser is the only RSS feeder I used that is any use.

I tried pretty much every other one out there and settled on it.  Give it a go.

http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux

When a feed is installed in Opera, it will fetch back the history of that feed as far back as the feed goes.  If you want to export your Google reader data, you can import it to Opera by following instructions here below.  Just export your Google Reader info as OPML :)
http://www.ghacks.net/2011/05/18/how-to-import-rss-feeds-into-opera/

You can then set that feed to be read.  Opera supports two kinds of unread markers.  Items are blue and bolded when new.  When you click on it, it goes black to show you've clicked on it and when your done reading it and you mark it read, it goes unbolded.  If you mark it read and it goes unbolded, the blue goes away too since your saying you want to mark it as read.

Or you can delete items from the feed entirely.

http://help.opera.com/Windows/10.51/en/feeds.html

It will auto-recognise feeds like it says in the link above and you can search feeds like their email and do most of the things you can do with email with the feed like forward it etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using newsblur ever since the reader shutdown was announced and it beats pulse and feedly by wide margins.  You have to pay for over 20 feeds but it's worth it, and if you don't want to pay, the source code is hosted on github and you can install it on your own host.  Newsblur will import your reader feeds and updates the feeds and unread counts in real-time.  There is an android and ios app as well.

http://www.newsblur.com